# Shortlist - showing only one item

Tags: ee2, shortlist

I am trying to show a list of items (as bookmarked).
However, the list only displays one item.

```
{exp:shortlist:view}
    {if count != ""}
    <div class="widget clearfix">
        <h4>My Bookmarked Items ({total_results})</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>{title} (<a href="{remove_url}">Remove</a>)</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    {/if}
    <p>{if no_results}Your list is empty{/if}</p>
{/exp:shortlist:view}
```

There are two items in the list, when seen from the backend. However, only one is getting listed.

Comment: This seems like a cache problem. File Cache (EE2's default). Shortlist misbehaves when cache is on. When cache is off, everything is red roses!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
{if count != ""}
```

to:

```
{if count==1}
```

Hopefully that sorts it out :)
- I noticed that your code was a little different to [the docs](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/shortlist/usage/examples/basic-example)...

Comment: I tried another version. It works. However, an entry doesn't get removed properly.

<div class="widget quick-contact-widget clearfix">
    <h4>My Bookmarked Jobs</h4>
    <ul class="iconlist">
    {exp:shortlist:view}
        {if count != ""}
        <li><i class="icon-ok success bold"></i> {title} (<a href="{exp:shortlist:auto_remove}{remove_url}{/exp:shortlist:auto_remove}">Remove</a>)</li>
        {/if}
        {if no_results}<li>Your list is empty</li>{/if}
    {/exp:shortlist:view}
    </ul>
</div>

Comment: It removes the item from the control panel, however it is listed in the ul li and also the link at the end shows {remove-url}, which is invalid.

Comment: Guessing it is a cache issue. Because it shows/gets removed after a while. It's happening when you add an entry or remove an entry.